# Returning top 50% of list whilst evenly splitting rows between object property

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have the following object

```
public string Quote { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

I have a List of this object, sample data as:

[image]

I am trying to return a new list which will evenly distribute between each FirstName (Same amount) and return 50% of the rows.

In the above Example, I have 20 rows, returning half gives 10. There are 4 different FirstNames to which John = 2, Mark = 2, Phil = 2, bob = 2 - There are 2 slots remaining which 2 *Different* random names are chosen.

So how do i do the grouping so the FirstNames are evenly distributed? and is the 50% taken first or last?

New to LINQ and filtering through data so help is appreciated :)

Comment: What if there is only one John ? What if there are 10 Bobs, 6 Johns, 2 Phils and 2 Marks? Should proportions be preserved?

Comment: Using the example above, it can get replaced with 1 of a different FirstName

Comment: Following [mre], Input and expectde output should be exploitable. It would be nice to have it in something copy pastable.

Comment: You also ask if the element will be taken first or last. In fact you have to define if you want the grouped data "_John = 2, Mark = 2, Phil = 2, bob = 2_". To be picked up in asc or desc or random order from the grouping on the source list.

Answer (score 0):

LinQ is not the most efficient way As we will be ieterating multiple time the same collection in roder to get basic count etc.
But lets do it Step by step.

#### Data generation:

That part was missing from the original question. You can change the repatition of name adding duplicate values in `names` collection.

```
// Data generation, Tuple because Im lazy.
var names = new[] { "Toto", "John", "John", "John", "Foo", "Foo", "Bar" };
var datas = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                     .Select(x => (Id: x + 1, Name: names[x % names.Length]));
```

#### Basic Count:

As we are given a percentage we need to know how many element it represent.

```
// Input value
var wantedPercent = 10;

// Counting, may be more efficient to iterate that list only once doing grouping and both count in one go
var totalCount = datas.Count();
var distinctNames = datas.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().Count();


int wantedSize = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalCount * (wantedPercent / 100.0));
int maxGroupSize = wantedSize / distinctNames; // Integer division :  1.9999 -> 1
```

#### Grouping:

This is the core issue. We need to group by on name.
And for each element of those group we will number them based on maxsize of a group.
If that number exceed the max size we keep them for remaining slots.

```
var grpDatas = datas.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                    .SelectMany(g =>
                        g.Select((x, i) => 
                            new { Item =x, newGroupingKey = i < maxGroupSize}
                        )
                    )
                    .GroupBy(x=> x.newGroupingKey);
```

#### Populate :

Let's take the item of the first group.

```
var result = grpDatas.First(x=> x.Key)
                     .Select(g=> g.Item)
                     .ToList();
```

You can have a remaining slot even if  `wantedSize / distinctNames` is round.
Because one group size may be lower than the Max Allowed Size.

```
var remainingSlot = wantedSize - result.Count();
if (remainingSlot > 0){
    var random = new Random();
    var shuffledGroup2 = grpDatas.First(x => !x.Key)
                                 .Select(g => g.Item)
                                 .OrderBy(a => random.Next());

    var remaining = shuffledGroup2.Take(remainingSlot);

    result.AddRange(remaining);
}
```

#### Result : [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ViLhcE)

```
[
 { "Id": 1, "Name": "Toto" },
 { "Id": 8, "Name": "Toto" },
 { "Id": 2, "Name": "John" },
 { "Id": 3, "Name": "John" },
 { "Id": 5, "Name": "Foo" },
 { "Id": 6, "Name": "Foo" },
 { "Id": 7, "Name": "Bar" },
 { "Id": 14, "Name": "Bar" },
 { "Id": 83, "Name": "Foo" }, // random
 { "Id": 85, "Name": "Toto" } // random
]
```